# Maximise function using scipy minimize

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to optimize my function `Strategy2(alpha, beta)`, which performs a betting strategy on some data, starting with a wallet value of *20,000*, and returns a new wallet value.

So I need to find the optimum `alpha` & `beta` values that maximize the returned value.

A quick google suggests that scipy is the way to go, but I am struggling to implement it.

Before attempting this optimization approach I took the approach of fixing alpha, and then finding the optimum beta, then doing the same with fixing beta and finding the optimum alpha.

That approach gave an optimum of `Strategy2(23,3)` which returned *24,650*.

Here is my attempt to implement the minimize method found in the module scipy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
```

```
bnds = ((None, None), (None, None))
param = [0, 0]
f = lambda param: Strategy2(param[0], param[1])
param_init = 0, 100
param = minimize(f, param_init, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds).x
print(param)
```

As you can see, I don't really know what I am doing, indeed this simply just returns

```
[  0. 100.]
```

with a final wallet value of  *10,705*. Which is clearly less than *24,650*. So something is clearly not working.

How can I get it so I maximize `Strategy2(alpha, beta)`? Ideally I want to vary alpha from 0 to 100, and vary beta from 1 to 15.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My reasoning for the above code was that I was just trying to adapt the following working code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import lsq_linear, minimize
bnds = ((None, None), (None, None))
fun = lambda param: np.linalg.norm(-np.exp(param[0]) + param[1])
param_init = -4, 4
param = minimize(fun, param_init, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds).x
```

which correctly minimise the above function.

If there is a better way to maximise my function then please let me know.

Comment: _here is my attempt to implement scipy_ <- `scipy` is a library, or a module, containing various data structures and functions. I am not sure what you mean when you say _...implement scipiy..._. Additionally, there is not much we can test here given the code you posted. Please post a minimal, verifiable, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've edited the comment to clarify what I meant regarding scipy.

Answer (score 3):

If your `Strategy2(alpha, beta)` returns the wallet value then your objective function `f` should be inverted. Minimizing `f` should be equivalent to maximizing `Strategy2(alpha, beta)`, which is not the case in your code. I suggest using:

```
bnds = ((None, None), (None, None))
param = [0, 0]
f = lambda param: 1 / Strategy2(param[0], param[1])
param_init = 0, 100
param = minimize(f, param_init, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds).x
print(param)
```

In this case, if `f` is minimized then`Strategy2()` is maximized.
I also suggest using some bounds to limit your search space (good for speed and efficiency).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the code so that the function is inverted, but it still returns: [  0. 100.]

It appears to just be running the function with the parameters [0,100] repeatedly but not varying them, and so just returns [0,100] as the optimal value

Comment: Is there a rationale for why 1/f is better than -f when trying to maximize a function?  I've always wondered which is better.

Comment: The choice of an obj. func is very decisive. I cannot explain it perfectly, cuz I am also not very knowledgeable in this topic. But to give you a quick idea; most optimizations rely on gradient decent, the Hessian and the Jacobian. To keep it simple, consider a 1d-function where the equivalents are the derivative funcs.

Comment: Take f(x) = 1-x, in the case of -f(x), the 1st derivative that will be used to advance the optimization is a constant =-1 where as in the case of 1/f(x) it is = 1/(1-x)^2. I think that the 2nd variant would probably lead to a more sensitive optimization, and the 1st might even miss the optimum.